# Facebook: how to do sharer as popup

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-sharer

I know that sharer has 2 params. There are url (u) and title (t):

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[url]&t=[title]`

I want that sharer display as popup window. How do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Open it with Javascript `window.open` method:

```
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[url]&t=[title]', 'facebook_share', 'height=320, width=640, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no');
```

Comment: Awesome. If only Facebook would swap their links out like this automatically like Twitter's Intents JS does...